# What does square bracket [] mean in the below code?why use [] around the ‘image' word?

Tags: swift

What does square bracket [] mean in the below code?why use [] around the ‘image' word?

```
let image = UIImage()
let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Presumably because the argument should be an [array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `activityItems` is of type "array of `image`". Without the `[]`, `activityItems` would be of type `image`.

Comment: activityItems it is not array of images. activityItems expects `[Any]` which can contain also strings. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller/1622019-init

Comment: so in this code it expect an array，do I understand it right?

Comment: @LeoDabus - Well, yes, the constructor accepts `[Any]`, but the actual argument is an array containing the single element `image`.

Comment: @user8780234 - Yes, the initializer expects an array. The code you posted is passing an array containing a single element, `image`.

Comment: so image itself is an one element array？this line of code    `let image = UIImage()`     defines the one element array

Comment: @user8780234 - I'm not saying that `image` is an array. I'm saying that `[image]` is a one-element array that contains the value currently assigned to `image`. It could be an array or (as your comment indicates) a single image or anything else.